# SQL Merge not working

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

Hi I have followed the DB2 documentation (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/sqlp/rbafymerge.htm) for MERGE and have come up with the below statement.

```
MERGE INTO TEMP2 target USING TEMP1 source 
     ON target.ITNBR = source.ITNBR        
          AND target.STID = source.STID    
          AND target.ITRV = source.ITRV    
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN                      
   INSERT VALUES(TEMP1.*)                  
WHEN MATCHED THEN                          
   UPDATE SET ITNBR = source.ITNBR
```

But this is failing with the below error:

Keyword SOURCE not expected. Valid tokens: FULL LEFT CROSS INNER RIG

I am not understanding whats wrong here. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

So the issue is because SOURCE is a DB2 keyword. I changed it to another word and works like a Gem. Why would IBM give such an example in their official documentation???

Comment: maybe you should open a documentation PMR with IBM to get that fixed.

Comment: Yes Mark! not sure how to do this but will definitely find out and do. Hope Nobody  goes to this and wastes time when frantically trying to complete your piece of code :P

Comment: @user3311539 The linked page has a 'Feedback' link at the bottom, and a 'Contact' link should also float near the bottom. Otherwise phone or e-mail your IBM support.

Answer (score 0):

So IBM have confirmed this is an issue and have agreed to rectify in a future release:

```
From: Nathan R Skalsky [mailto:skalsky@us.ibm.com] 
Sent: Tuesday, February 14, 2017 4:34 AM
To: Thejwal Pavithran <Thejwal.Pavithran@polaris.com>
Subject: RE: Feedback to IBM Knowledge Center - Content page/ssw_ibm_i_71/IBM i 7.1

Hi Thejwal, 

Unfortunately, this is not our normal channel of communication; Therefore, I will not be posting to the specified thread.
Your welcome to communicate it.

Thanks,

Nathan R. Skalsky
IBM i Software Engineer - DB2 for IBM i Development
________________________________________

E-mail: skalsky@us.ibm.com
Internal: Nathan R Skalsky/Rochester/IBM 


3605 Hwy 52 N
Rochester, MN 55901-1407
United States





From:        Thejwal Pavithran <Thejwal.Pavithran@polaris.com>
To:        Nathan R Skalsky/Rochester/IBM@IBMUS
Date:        02/13/2017 11:53 AM
Subject:        RE: Feedback to IBM Knowledge Center - Content page/ssw_ibm_i_71/IBM i 7.1
________________________________________



Thanks Nathan!

Would be great if you could post a reply on the Stack Overflow thread for the sake of all users.

Thanks,
Thejwal


      Thejwal Pavithran | IBMi Developer
        7th Floor, ‘Electra’, Wing A, Prestige Tech Park, Marathalli| Bangalore – 560103 | Karnataka
        Direct line: | Cell: +91 9620661497
        thejwal.pavithran@Polaris.com| www.polaris.com

From: Nathan R Skalsky [mailto:skalsky@us.ibm.com] 
Sent: Monday, February 13, 2017 11:21 PM
To: Thejwal Pavithran <Thejwal.Pavithran@polaris.com>
Subject: Feedback to IBM Knowledge Center - Content page/ssw_ibm_i_71/IBM i 7.1 

Hi Theywal,

Thank you for your bringing this to my attention.  We will fix this in a future technical refresh (TR) of  the SQL Programming topic in 7.2 and 7.3.
The fix will remove the word SOURCE from these examples.

Thanks,

Nathan R. Skalsky
IBM i Software Engineer - DB2 for IBM i Development
________________________________________

E-mail: skalsky@us.ibm.com
Internal: Nathan R Skalsky/Rochester/IBM 


3605 Hwy 52 N
Rochester, MN 55901-1407
United States




Thejwal Pavithran ---02/12/2017 03:08:33 AM---Hi Team, Have come across a minor issue in DB2 MERGE syntax at below page.

From: Thejwal Pavithran <Thejwal.Pavithran@polaris.com>
To: IBM Knowledge Center/Pittsburgh/IBM@IBMUS
Date: 02/12/2017 03:08 AM
Subject: Feedback to IBM Knowledge Center - Content page/ssw_ibm_i_71/IBM i 7.1
________________________________________




Hi Team, 
Have come across a minor issue in DB2 MERGE syntax at below page.
URL: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/sqlp/rbafymerge.htm
Issue described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151989/sql-merge-not-working/42152283?noredirect=1#comment71511658_42152283
Please attempt to rectify.
Thanks,
Thejwal


     Thejwal Pavithran | IBMi Developer
       7th Floor, ‘Electra’, Wing A, Prestige Tech Park, Marathalli| Bangalore – 560103 | Karnataka
       Direct line: | Cell: +91 9620661497
       thejwal.pavithran@Polaris.com| www.polaris.com


Thanks,

Nathan R. Skalsky
IBM i Software Engineer - DB2 for IBM i Development
________________________________________

Phone:(507) 253-1685
T/L: (507) 553-1685
Fax: (507) 253-4728
Office: 15-3 C118
E-mail: skalsky@us.ibm.com
Internal: Nathan R Skalsky/Rochester/IBM 


3605 Hwy 52 N
Rochester, MN 55901-1407
United States

CONFIDENTIAL: The information contained in this email communication is confidential information intended only for the use of the addressee. Unauthorized use, disclosure or copying of this communication is strictly prohibited and may be unlawful. If you have received this communication in error, please notify us immediately by return email and destroy all copies of this communication, including all attachments.
```